# Can't figure out how to store command line arguments correctly

Tags: c, arguments, command-line-arguments, program-entry-point

I need to store two command line arguments, but I can't figure out how to do so correctly. My code currently stores an int that isn't correct (if I set the second variable to nothing) and gives an error saying invalid initialization. I tried initializing name with strcpy and strcat but that didn't help either because I got different errors mostly relating to casting.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(int argcount, char *args[])
{
   int number = *args[1];
   char name[] = *args[2];


   printf("number is %d and name is %s\n", number, name);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You won't get far just trying random things with C. Go back to your textbook/tutor/online course to see why `int number = *args[1];` and `char name[] = *args[2];` are nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what your main function should look like:

```
int main(int argcount, char **args)
{
   int number = atoi(args[1]); // atoi() converts your string to an int
   char *name = args[2]; // Do not dereference twice, otherwise you get a char


   printf("number is %d and name is %s\n", number, name);

   return 0;
}
```

`int number = *args[1];` is wrong because `args[1]` is your first argument, and `*argv[1]` (or `argv[1][0]`) is the first letter of your argument. Putting this in your `number` variable will actually result in the ASCII value of the first letter of your first parameter been stocked in `number`. This is absolutely not what you want.

`char name[] = *args[2];` isn't correct either because here, you are trying to get the first letter of your second parameter (`*args[2]`, or `args[2][0]`), which is a type `char` and put it inside an array of `char`.

You might also want to check how many arguments your program gets and if these arguments are well formatted, otherwise your program could crash!

Answer (score -1):

Please note that **all cmdline args are given in string** (a series of characters, so if you want to use them as their literal meaning, you have to convert them:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int number = atoi(args[1]);
char *name = args[2];
```

If you want to copy `args[2]`, you should use `strcpy`:

```
#include <string.h>

char name[1+strlen(args[2])];
strcpy(name, args[2]);

// Now this works:
printf("number is %d and name is %s\n", number, name);
```

Finally, it is recommended that you check if there's enough arguments given, so that you won't access `args` out of bound.